# Help solving an improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

The assignment is to solve:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx
$$
where
$$f(x) = \frac{4}{(x+1)^2(x+3)} $$
.

I did partial fraction on the indefinite integral of $f(x)$ and got:
$$
f(x) = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{C}{x+3}
$$
$$
4=(A+C)x^3 + (5A+B+3C)x^2 + (7A+4B+3C)x + (3A + 3B + C)
$$
and put the last three functions inside a matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
7 & 4 & 3 & 0 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
gauss elimination:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -9 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Replace $A$, $B$ and $C$ with the result in $f(x)$:

$$
f(x) = \frac{-9}{x+1} + \frac{6}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{3}{x+3}
$$

Calculate the definite integral from 0 to $\infty$:

$$
\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{0}^{b} f(x)dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} (-9 \log|b+1|- \frac{6}{b+1} + 13 \log|b+3| + 6 - 13\log(3))
$$

Separate into several limits:
$$
\lim_{b \to \infty}(-9 \log|b+1|- \frac{6}{b+1} + 13 \log|b+3|) + 6 - 13\log(3)
$$

L'Hopital:
$$
\lim_{b \to \infty}(\frac{9}{b+1} + \frac{6}{(b+1)^2} + \frac{13}{b+3}) + 6 - 13\log(3)
$$

All limits are zero, so we're just left with the constants:
$$
6 - 13\log(3)
$$

which is not the correct answer.

Comment: You did partial fraction, not partial integration.

Comment: @PinkPanther correct, my bad. edited

Comment: something is wrong, note that the limit is equivalent to the limit of $\ln\left|\frac{(b+3)^{13}}{(b+1)^9}\right|+6-13\ln 3$ what is infinity

Comment: @Masacroso yes something is wrong. What do you mean by "what is infinity"?

Comment: I mean that $$\lim_{b \to \infty}(-9 \log|b+1|- \frac{6}{b+1} + 13 \log|b+3|) + 6 - 13\log(3)\\=\lim_{b\to\infty}\ln\left|\frac{(b+3)^{13}}{(b+1)^9}\right|+6-13\ln 3=\infty$$

Comment: I would not recommend this method for partial fraction decomposition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was that this equation

$$4=(A+C)x^3 + (5A+B+3C)x^2 + (7A+4B+3C)x + (3A + 3B + C)$$

was wrong. You start from

$$\frac4{(x+1)^2(x+3)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+3}$$

Hence, assuming that $x\neq-1$ or $x\neq-3$, you have that

$$4=A(x+1)(x+3)+B(x+3)+C(x+1)^2\\
\iff (A+C)x^2+(4A+B+2C)x+3A+3B+C=4$$

Thus the system to be solved is

$$A+C=0,\quad 4A+B+2C=0,\quad 3A+3B+C=4$$

what gives the solutions $A=-1,\, B=2$ and $C=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You found the partial fractions incorrectly
$$\frac4{(x+1)^2(x+3)}=\frac1{x+3}-\frac1{x+1}+\frac2{(x+1)^2}$$
So the integral becomes
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\ln{(t+3)}-\ln{(t+1)}-\frac2{t+1}-\ln{(3)}+2\right)=2-\ln{(3)}$$
Also, you cannot apply L'Hopitals rule unless you have an indeterminate form of
$$\frac00 \text{ or } \frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$$

Comment: What's wrong with the way I found the partial fractions, I don't see my mistake

Comment: See the other answer by Masacroso